# Internal Pull-Up (PU) for LATTICE ICE40 LP1k

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, fpga, embedded, lattice

I'm using [AD8541](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8541_8542_8544.pdf) Amplifier as a Power Good indicator for +VCCST_CPU that comes from Intel Tiger Lake UP3 on the motherboard I'm building.

[image]

The outputs V5S_OK and VCCST_CPU_OK go to an [ICE40 LP1k](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5h49wl8d96o2mwh/FPGA-DS-02029-3-7-iCE40-LP-HX-Family-Data-Sheet.pdf?dl=0) FPGA.

How do I know if I need to set a weak pull-up to these signals inside the FPGA? The datasheet doesn't specify these pins as open-drain so how should I treat them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The outputs V5S_OK and VCCST_CPU_OK go to ICE40 LP1k FPGA. how do I
> know if I need to set a weak pull-up to these signals inside the FPGA?*

The op-amp in your schematic ([LMV358](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmv358.pdf?ts=1639309818855&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLMV358)) produces voltage outputs on pins 1 and 7 so, they are not to be regarded as open-drain. However, there \$\color{red}{\text{(may be)}}\$ a problem with the input to that op-amp because the maximum input voltage allowed is typically 4.2 volts and, if you do the numbers on pin 5, with a 5 volt supply \$\color{red}{\text{(if it is 5 volts)}}\$, it will see 4.545 volts: -

[image]

You should also be aware that if your FPGA is running on a supply rail lower than the op-amp, the voltage outputs on pins 1 and 7 may cause it damage.

Edits in \$\color{red}{\text{red}}\$

Comment: Thanks. VCCST_CPU is 1.05V, so I guess I'm O.K.

Comment: @Xhero39 no, I don't think so. What is the IO voltage supply for your FPGA. If it's lower than 5 volts (and it might easily be so) then you need to use resistor voltage dividers from the op-amp to interface it without damage.

Comment: the LATTICE fpga VCCIO is 3.3V. If I understand right, your fear is that pin 1 and 7 will will have a 5V output? but the VCC of LMV358 is 3.3V. (pin 8 in picture above)

Comment: @Xhero39 you are of course absolutely correct. I saw one power rail at `+5VS` and got swept along.

Comment: Yep. But it's always good to keep that fact in mind.